# python 2.7 file overwritten even after using "a" (threads and filelock used)

Tags: python, multithreading, append, overwrite, filelock

I've a loop generating threads every 5 seconds and each thread is trying to append same file using filelock module in python but looks like they end up over-writing the file

```
import threading
import filelock

def loop():

    threading.Timer(5,loop).start()
    lock = filelock.FileLock("PATH", timeout=20)
    with lock.acquire(timeout=0.1, poll_intervall=0.01):
        with open("PATH", "a") as myFile:
            myFile.write("DATA\n\n")
    lock.release()
```

Edit: Additional Info:
After multiple iteration, the data I found in the file was from last thread and not the first.

Edit: as commented by georgexsh below, append is atomic and hence we don't need lock for it.

Comment: The docs seem to say that the file parameter in `FileLock` should not be written to.

Comment: I'm writing to external file and not the file parameter given by FileLock class.

Comment: Your call to `FileLock` quotes "PATH". Your `open()` call also quotes "PATH". It looks to me that you are using "PATH" both as the lock and the file that you want to write to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using this [filelock package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filelock), as your code use the lock object as a context manager for `with` statement, the lock would be released when the `with` block is exited.

write data to lock file is not a wise idea, lock file will be truncated to length 0 when acquiring the lock, [as `O_TRUNC` being used](https://github.com/benediktschmitt/py-filelock/blob/master/filelock.py#L376).

if you change inner `with` block to:

```
import time

with lock.acquire(timeout=0.1, poll_intervall=0.01):
    with open("PATH", "a") as myFile:
        myFile.write("DATA\n\n")
    time.sleep(1000)
```

the first thread which acquired the file lock will hold it, other threads would be blocked as you expected.

---

Comment: In my case I see the file has data from latest thread and data from all previous threads are removed. Also I can't use time.sleep() as my code is supposed to be time conscious. Yes, I'm using filelock package.

Comment: @ubanthia what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to append data in a file via multiple python script and each script releasing new thread every few seconds. For Algo trading purposes.

Comment: append is atomic, dont need lock protection, and plz update your original question

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean to do this:

```
import threading
import filelock

def loop():

    threading.Timer(5,loop).start()
    lock = filelock.FileLock("FILELOCK", timeout=20)
    with lock.acquire(timeout=0.1, poll_intervall=0.01):
        with open("PATH", "a") as myFile:
            myFile.write("DATA\n\n")
    # lock.release() <== release not needed after 'with'?
```

This code uses the file `FILELOCK` as a locking mechanism. This will leave file "PATH" free to hold the contents you need.

I am guessing that in your original code, the `FileLock` software writes something to the file (not using append) which clears out the file and the last thread that calls `open` and `write` writes to the beginning of the file.

Comment: actually there is no last write....all the writes are 'append' and by the code mentioned above. I got the solution from georgexsh that locks are not needed for append but I still can't explain its behavior.